# how to auto increment cell id's when cloning table row using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been researching a lot into this and I'm struggling to find a method that works for specifically for what i want to do.

I'm able to clone the rows and auto increment the id name for the row but I can't seem to do this for the `td's`. For the loop I am using an input where the user says how many `row's` they want to create. I want to add to a number to the end of the cell id for every time the function loops.

```js
function cloneRow() {
  var rowAmmount = document.getElementById("rowAmmount").value;
  for (var i = 1; i <= rowAmmount; i++) {
    var row = document.getElementById("row"); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("table"); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = "newRow" + i; // change id or other attributes/contents
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    var tag = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    tag.id += i;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <input id="rowAmmount">
  <button id="add" onclick="cloneRow()">New Row</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  <select id="select">
    <option value="html">HTML</option>
    <option value="packlist">Packlist</option>
  </select>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <tr>
        <th>Fabric</th>
        <th>Fabric Input</th>
        <th>Style</th>
        <th>Colour</th>
        <th>Sizeguide</th>
        <th>Image Link</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table">
      <tr id="row">
        <td><input id="fabric" placeholder="Input"></td>
        <td><input id="fabricInput" placeholder="Input 'Yes' 'No' or 'Number'"></td>
        <td><input id="style" placeholder="Input"></td>
        <td><input id="colour" placeholder="Input"></td>
        <td><input id="sizeGuide" placeholder="Input File Name"></td>
        <td><input id="imageLink" placeholder="Input"></td>
        <td class="output"><img id="image" src=""></output>
        </td>
        <td class="output"><output id="name"></output></td>
        <td class="output"><output id="description"></output></td>

      </tr>
```

Comment: Why do you *need* to create all the `id`s ?

Comment: your html is so invalid

Comment: @TakitIsy - i am using a function that takes the values of the table inputs and automatically creates item names  and descriptions. i am collecting that information by using id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to do something like this:

- Start with an empty table, using `class="hidden"` to hide the "template" row,
- Use `.querySelectorAll('tr').length` to know how many `tr` your table contains,
- Use `.querySelectorAll("*[id]")` to get all your elements with `id`s and a `.forEach()` loop to change their `id`s using the number of `tr`s from the above method.

I used the above method to modify the existing `id`s of the `inputs`/`output`/`image` from the "template" after copying it, but it could be easy to add other `id`s on other elements (for example the `td`s).

Snippet:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");      // Find table to append to
var row_typical = document.getElementById("row");  // Find row to copy

function cloneRow() {
  var rowAmmount = document.getElementById("rowAmmount").value;
  for (var i = 1; i <= rowAmmount; i++) {
    var clone = row_typical.cloneNode(true);       // Copy typical row with children
    var num = table.querySelectorAll('tr').length; // Get current number of tr
    clone.id = "newRow" + num;                     // Change id of tr
    var ids = clone.querySelectorAll("*[id]");     // Get all elements with id in tr,
    ids.forEach(function(elm) {                    // For all ids
      elm.id += num;                               // Add the num of the tr
    });
    clone.classList.remove('hidden');              // Remove the "hidden" class
    table.appendChild(clone);                      // Add new row to end of table
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="rowAmmount" placeholder="Row Amount">
<button id="add" onclick="cloneRow()">New Row</button>
<button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<select id="select">
  <option value="html">HTML</option>
  <option value="packlist">Packlist</option>
</select>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fabric</th>
      <th>Fabric Input</th>
      <th>Style</th>
      <th>Colour</th>
      <th>Sizeguide</th>
      <th>Image Link</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr class="hidden" id="row">
      <td><input id="fabric" placeholder="Input"></td>
      <td><input id="fabricInput" placeholder="Input 'Yes' 'No' or 'Number'"></td>
      <td><input id="style" placeholder="Input"></td>
      <td><input id="colour" placeholder="Input"></td>
      <td><input id="sizeGuide" placeholder="Input File Name"></td>
      <td><input id="imageLink" placeholder="Input"></td>
      <td class="output"><img id="image" src=""></td>
      <td class="output"><output id="name"></output></td>
      <td class="output"><output id="description"></output></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function cloneRow() {
  var rowAmmount = document.getElementById("rowAmmount").value;
  var getTotalRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].children.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowAmmount; i++) {
    var row = document.getElementById("row"); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("table"); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = "newRow" + (getTotalRows + i); // change id or other attributes/contents
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    var children = document.getElementById('newRow' + (getTotalRows + i)).children;
    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
      var tableChild = children[j].children;
      tableChild[0].setAttribute('id', tableChild[0].getAttribute('id') + (getTotalRows + i));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="rowAmmount">
<button id="add" onclick="cloneRow()">New Row</button>
<button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<select id="select">
  <option value="html">HTML</option>
  <option value="packlist">Packlist</option>
</select>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fabric</th>
      <th>Fabric Input</th>
      <th>Style</th>
      <th>Colour</th>
      <th>Sizeguide</th>
      <th>Image Link</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr id="row">
      <td><input id="fabric" placeholder="Input"></td>
      <td><input id="fabricInput" placeholder="Input 'Yes' 'No' or 'Number'"></td>
   <td><input id="style" placeholder="Input"></td>
      <td><input id="colour" placeholder="Input"></td>
      <td><input id="sizeGuide" placeholder="Input File Name"></td>
      <td><input id="imageLink" placeholder="Input"></td>
      <td class="output"><img id="image" src=""></output></td>
   <td class="output"><output id="name"></output></td>
   <td class="output"><output id="description"></output></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this.

Check the snippet below.

```js
function cloneRow() {
  var rowAmmount = document.getElementById("rowAmmount").value;
  var added = document.querySelectorAll("tbody#table tr").length;
  for (var i = 1; i <= rowAmmount; i++) {
    var row = document.getElementById("row"); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("table"); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = "newRow" + (i + added); // change id or other attributes/contents
    console.log(clone.id);
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    var tag = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    tag.id += i;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <input id="rowAmmount">
  <button id="add" onclick="cloneRow()">New Row</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  <select id="select">
    <option value="html">HTML</option>
    <option value="packlist">Packlist</option>
  </select>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <col width: "130" />
      <tr>
        <th>Fabric</th>
        <th>Fabric Input</th>
        <th>Style</th>
        <th>Colour</th>
        <th>Sizeguide</th>
        <th>Image Link</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table">
      <tr id="row">
        <td><input id="fabric" placeholder="Input"></td>
        <td><input id="fabricInput" placeholder="Input 'Yes' 'No' or 'Number'"></td>
        <td><input id="style" placeholder="Input"></td>
        <td><input id="colour" placeholder="Input"></td>
        <td><input id="sizeGuide" placeholder="Input File Name"></td>
        <td><input id="imageLink" placeholder="Input"></td>
        <td class="output"><img id="image" src=""></output>
        </td>
        <td class="output"><output id="name"></output></td>
        <td class="output"><output id="description"></output></td>

      </tr>
```

Comment: Your code is not adding `id`s on the `td`s, I checked in the code inspector. Plus, you're letting the incrreoct (duplicate) `id`s of the `inputs`, `output` and `image` elements.